# I can't change the background color of a specific page

Tags: css

I'm trying with no luck to change the background color of just one page. I've tried adding  > and then using the selector

```
body.page-id-15 #content { background-color:#000000; }
```

This doesn't work. Seems the only way I can change the background to that page is changing the background of #content. But...that changes all pages. I know this is possible and I've done it before. But not with this theme

Any ideas? The link the page in question is here http://gregtregunno.ca/news
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your pages source, it does not have post/page ID's being added to the page's body class so you referencing something in your CSS that doesn't exist.

Try this rather (not sure what section you want changed):

```
body.blog {
    background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
body.blog #content {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put some conditional code in the header.php file that inserts a style into the header only for your specific page ID (15 in the example):

```
<head>
<?php if(is_page(15)): ?>

<style>
body.page {background-color: #FF0000 !important;}
</style>

<?php endif; ?>
</head>
```